# Copying values (numbers) from a large text

Tags: linux

I have a huge file and want to copy out a set of numbers to another text file in column format so that I can plot the data.

- The text

  ```
  CC for particle      1 is  0.05378168  phase residual is  78.77

  values of PSI,THETA,PHI at FMATCH extraction   88.780   62.638  352.976
  Time before particle       2 was  19:31:43

  CC for particle      2 is  0.05370924  phase residual is  79.34

  values of PSI,THETA,PHI at FMATCH extraction   88.399  123.675  354.108

  CC for particle      3 is  0.04939323  phase residual is  78.30

  values of PSI,THETA,PHI at FMATCH extraction   87.646   98.585  353.899

  CC for particle      4 is  0.05664483  phase residual is  79.33

  values of PSI,THETA,PHI at FMATCH extraction   87.755  116.152  350.454

  CC for particle      5 is  0.06687291  phase residual is  78.83
  ```

I want to extract the phase residual values at the end of the line in **bold**. 
How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your example, I assume you always have `is` before the numbers you want:

```
sed -n 's/.*is *\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\)$/\1/p' input
```

This should get the bold numbers you want, but if you want you can be more strict:

```
sed -n 's/.*phase residual is *\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\)$/\1/p' input
```

Comment: Hi @perreal. Thanks much for the quick response! The work 'is' also there in "CC for particle      4 is.." I want to have only the values in bold i.e. the value comes after - 'phase residual is'  79.33. How can we modify it.

Comment: the above should not match `particle 4 is..` due to the `$` (end of line) marker in the regex. does it not produce desired output?

Comment: hi @Perreal worked like a magic. THANKS A LOT ! May I also enquire any weblink where sed examples are provided as I am new to this level of scripting.